# Block Windows clipboard from user with Python while Program running

Tags: python, clipboard, pywin32, win32com, pyperclip

I want to make it impossible for a user to copy data to the clipboard as long as my program is running. How would I go about to do that in Python ?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply render the text as a graphic.
This way selecting text would not be possible.

I have to point out, that stuff like this is always a bad idea, and if the user wants to get the text, he will.
In the past I used screenshots with OCR to get texts.

It's not worth the effort, and in most cases doing stuff like this will just result in the user not wanting to use your program.